# Coldfusion - Can't login after NEQ check

Tags: coldfusion

```
<cffunction name="checkUsers" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="dbname"   type="any" required="no" default="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDBName()#" />
    <cfargument name="myForm" type="Struct" required="yes">

    <cfset LOCAL = structNew() />

    <cfquery name="Login" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">            
        SELECT * 
        FROM logboek.tbl_users 
        where Users_name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.Users_name#" />    
    </cfquery>

    <cfif isDefined("form.Users_name") and isDefined("form.Users_password")>
        <cfif FORM.Users_password EQ login.Users_password>
            <a href="http://toomba.local/index.cfm/action/blog.Logboek">Logboek</a>
        </cfif>

    <cfelse>
        <a href="http://toomba.local/index.cfm/action/blog.Logboek_login">Login</a>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

i want a check with the users if the user exists and password is correct go to `blog.logboek` if the user doesn't exists or password is incorrect go to `blog.logboek_login` again. But after I put the `NEQ` check in there, it doesn't matter if I use a random password or if I use the correct password it would always go back to login page. code is edited but still stuck on login page.

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  `<cfdump>` is your friend.

Comment: You should also be hashing your passwords. If you're storing plain text passwords that should be fixed immediately.

Comment: As Dan noted, don't just assume the logic is correct ;-) Dump the data and add some debugging code to verify the page is receiving the values expected AND verify the expected cfif / cfelse conditions are being executed. Also, the code also appears to be mixing tests of the `arguments` and `form` scopes. For functions, stick with the arguments scope, and do not forget to localize all function local variables - including query names.

Comment: You don't specify which version of ColdFusion you are running. If version 9 or later, you should remove the `<cfset LOCAL = structNew() />` statement as "local" is an actual function local scope now.

Answer (score -1):

here i have the fix:

```
<cffunction name="checkUsers" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="dbname"   type="any" required="no" default="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDBName()#" />
    <cfargument name="myForm" type="Struct" required="yes">

    <cfset LOCAL = structNew() />
    <cfset LOCAL.myReturn = FALSE />
    <cfquery name="Login" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">            
        SELECT * 
        FROM logboek.tbl_users 
        WHERE Users_name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.Users_name#" />    
    </cfquery>
    <cfif isDefined("form.Users_name") and isDefined("form.Users_password")>
        <cfif FORM.Users_password EQ Login.Users_password>
            <cfset LOCAL.myReturn = TRUE />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset LOCAL.myReturn = FALSE />    
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn LOCAL.myReturn/>
</cffunction>
```